# Mutithreading in django when interactiong with database, what i need to know and pay attention to?

Tags: python, django, database, multithreading, django-celery

My site will need to parse large amounts of data from multiple web pages in regular intervals. I'm thinking about using celery or python threads to speed that up.

I'm afraid of hard to debug errors when interacting with database.
For example is it possible/ what will happen when 2 threads will call `SampleModel.object.get_or_create(name="same string")` at the same time?
Or what will happen if (simplified pseudocode to show the idea):

```
mymodel(models.Model)
      title = models.CharField()
      (...)
      owner = models.ManyToManyField(Creator)

def FindPageCreatorName(page):
    (...)
    return name
```

and in multiple threads i will call

```
def create_mymodel(url): #thats what will be run in each thread
    page = urllib.urlopen(url)
    mymodelInstance.title = FindPageTitle(page)
    (...)
    mymodelInstance.save()
    creator = Creator.get_or_create(name=FindPageCreatorName(page))
    mymodelInstance.creator.add(creator)
```

and it will find same creator name on multiple pages in roughly the same time?
(other thread will change database between another instructions)

Should i encapsulate each thread in transaction and it will be enough to prevent errors?

What are other scenarios that may not work as intended?
Or I shouldn't worry because nothing bad can happen, celery will take care of such things?

If you cant point me to any good tutorials or docs on this topic i will be grateful. Sorry for such vague question but i don't have a clue what specific problems may appear - thats the question.
Also it will be probably only thing in the code that needs to be multi threaded - should i use celery or python threads in that case? (isn't celery an overkill?)

Answer (score 1):

Bad things can certainly happen if you have enough requests per second.

What will happen if two threads call `SampleModel.object.get_or_create(name="same string")` simultaneously? What about if there are two processes instead? What if it is called by two worker nodes?

In cases like this, you need to think of where the failure might occur.

If you have two worker nodes accepting jobs from Celery, and if the two call a database operation simultaneously, there is nothing in the django code base that can provide any guarantee of what will happen.

If two different threads in the same process call the database action, they cannot call it simultaneously, since they are restricted by CPU access.

But if you do have multiple nodes, who hit the database, the database itself will execute them one after the other (there are exceptions). So in that case, you want to make sure that the database rejects the second `create` command. Depending on the database, this can be done by adding a unique index on the relevant fields.

You need to think your design through, and make sure you have sequential data writes in the database, if that is what you need. Parallel data writes, in certain databases, will provide much better performance, but won't provide data integrity.